# No method error on active storage with Rails 5.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, nomethoderror

In a rails engine using RSpec for testing, I have to list my rails frameworks instead of using include "rails/all" so the mini-test unit isn't created. I keep getting a no method error or active storage. Its a new feature of Rails 5.2 to enable storage on cloud sources, but I can't find a way to require that feature. I tried "activestorage" and activestorage/railties". I installed active storage.

```
# require 'rails/all'   # cannot use due to RSpec instead of mini-test
require "active_record/railtie"
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "action_view/railtie"
require "sprockets/railtie"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It'd be great to see a stack trace of what your error looks like. However, maybe this will help. For using Rails 5.2.0 with RSpec and ActiveStorage, this is what my `config/application.rb` looks like:

```
# config/application.rb

require 'rails'
# Pick the frameworks you want:
require 'active_model/railtie'
require 'active_job/railtie'
require 'active_record/railtie'
require 'active_storage/engine'
require 'action_controller/railtie'
require 'action_mailer/railtie'
require 'action_view/railtie'
require 'sprockets/railtie'
```

If the above doesn't help, please update your question with the command you ran and the full stack trace of the errors you're getting.

Comment: Adding require 'active_storage/engine' did the trick. Thank you, The Curious Cat! And thanks for directions on improving my questions in the future.

Comment: Great! Glad that helped!